# how do I add check boxes in form created with the Registration module?

Tags: 7, entities, users

I am getting a radio button in my form as default, but I want a checkbox.

I am using the Registration and the [Entitiy Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) modules. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of Field Creation.

Select **FIELD TYPE : List (text)**

Select **WIDGET : Check boxes/Radio buttons** & save

> **Allowed values list :**
>
> **1|list1**
>
> **2|list2**
>
> **3|list3**

& save field setting.

You see that radio buttons are shown.

Now in **FIELD SETTINGS** : Select **Number of values : Unlimited** & save.